# On the total derivative of a differential form.

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I look for an example of differential form $\omega$ of degree $r$ defined on a surface $ M \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ of dimension $m$ such that its derivative $D\omega$ can not be defined on the entire surface $ M $.

**Background.** Let $\omega$ be a differential form of degree $r$ and class $C^k$ ($k\geq 1$) defined on a surface $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C^s$ ($s > k $) of dimension $ m $.

To fix the ideas take $\omega$ as an application of $M$ in $\bigcup_{q\in M} \bigwedge^r(T_qM)$ which at each point $ p\in M $ associates a $r$-linear application in $\bigwedge^r(T_pM)$. I am assuming that the tangent plane $ T_{p^{\prime}} M $ varies to the tangent plane $ T_{p^{\prime \prime}} M $ in a differentiable manner (with regularity $ C^k $) as $ p^\prime $ varies to $p^{\prime \prime}$.

Let's fix an arbitrary point $ p\in M $. Let a parametrization $ \varphi: \overline{U} \to \widetilde{U} $ of $M$ and a curve $\overline{\alpha}: (-\epsilon, + \epsilon) \to \overline{U}$ satisfying
$$
(\ast)
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\varphi(u)=p, \\
\overline{\alpha}(0)=u.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The total derivative of $\omega $ should work as follows: each vector $ (\varphi\circ\overline{\alpha})^\prime (0)$ tangent to the curve $ \varphi \circ \overline{\alpha} :(-\epsilon, +\epsilon) \to M $ at the point $p \in M $ is taken by the derivative of $ \omega$ in the vector $ (\omega \circ\varphi\circ\overline{\alpha})^\prime(0) $ tangent to the curve $ \omega\circ\varphi \circ \overline{\alpha}: (- \epsilon, + \epsilon) \to \bigcup_{q \in M} \bigwedge (T_qM)$ at the point $\omega(p)$.

Suppose a second parametrization $ \psi: \overline{V} \to \widetilde{V} $ and a second curve $ \overline{\beta}: (- \epsilon, + \epsilon)\to \overline{V}$ satisfying the following properties:
$$
(\ast\ast)
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\widetilde{U}\cap\widetilde{V}\neq \emptyset\\
\psi(v)=\varphi(u) \\
\overline{\beta}(0)=v
\end{array}
\right.
$$
In order, for the total derivative of $ \omega $ to be well defined over the entire surface $ M $, the following property must be satisfied: for every $ p \in M $, for all parametrization $ \varphi $ and every curve $ \overline{\alpha} $ fulfilling the conditions $ (\ast) $ worth the equality
$$
(\omega\circ\varphi\circ\overline{\alpha})^{\prime}(0)= (\omega\circ\psi\circ\overline{\beta})^\prime(0).
$$
for any parametrization $ \psi $ and any curve $ \overline{\beta}$  that satisfies $ (\ast \ast) $.

> So the example to be looked for is an example where there is a $ M $ surface and a differential form $ \omega: M \to \bigcup_{q \in M} \bigwedge^r(T_qM) $ for which at a point $ p \in M $  there is a parameterization  $ \varphi $ and a curve $ \overline{\alpha}$  satisfying $ (\ast) $ and a parameterization $ \psi $ and a curve$ \overline{\beta}$  satisfying $ (\ast\ast) $ such that
>   $$
> (\omega\circ\varphi\circ\overline{\alpha})^{\prime}(0)\neq (\omega\circ\psi\circ\overline{\beta})^\prime(0).
> $$
>   Is there any classic example with the above property? Is there any reference where I can find such an example?

I was unable to find any reference who could be of some help in answer my question. The references I researched were as follows:

[Analysis On Manifolds by James R. Munkres](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201315963)

[An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. W. Tu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441973990)

[Vector Analysis by  Klaus Jänich](https://www.amazon.com.br/Vector-Analysis-L-Kay/dp/1441931449/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1547908310&sr=1-2&keywords=Vector%20Analysis%20Klaus%20Janich)

[A Visual Introduction to Differential Forms and Calculus on Manifolds 
by Jon Pierre Fortney](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319969919)

[Mathematical Analysis II by V. A. Zorich](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3662489910)

I would really appreciate if someone can give me some directions in the literature and, if possible give me an exemple.

Comment: I have no idea what $(\omega\circ\phi\circ\alpha)'(0)$ could possibly mean unless you're differentiating a vector-valued function (with values in a fixed vector space). And what does this have to do with the exterior derivative $d\omega$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, unless isomorphism we can consider $T_qM=\mathbb{R}^m$. Then for all $q\in M$ we have $\bigwedge^{r}(T_qM)=\bigwedge^{r}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ and $\bigcup_{q\in M}\bigwedge^{r}(T_qM)=\bigcup_{q\in M}\bigwedge^{r}(\mathbb{R}^m)=\bigwedge^{r}(\mathbb{R}^m)$. Here $\bigwedge^{r}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is a vector space.